# Is It possible to make this MySql code non-injectable in any way?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

Hello thanks to everyone for helping me with my current issue if so could you check if this code has any vulnerabilities as-well?

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO  `paypal_mysqltable_name` (datenow,    item_name,   item_number,       payment_status,    payment_amount,   payment_currency,  payer_email,     payment_type,   custom, 
invoice, first_name, last_name, address_name, address_country, address_country_code, address_zip, address_state, address_city, address_street) 
            VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'item_name','$item_number','$payment_status', '$payment_amount','$payment_currency','$payer_email', '$payment_type','$custom' ,'$invoice','$first_name','$last_name','$address_name','$address_country','$address_country_code','$address_zip','$address_state','$address_city','$address_street')";
  $result=mysql_query($sql,$link);
```

Hey everyone sorry im not very accustomed to SQL and php I have turned my $link into MYSQLi like recommended but I have a problem writing the statement that I presented into this format.

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
```

can anyone help

Comment: pelase and please use `PreparedStatement`

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: To prevent SQL Injection, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php Then, when *using* the data (e.g. outputting in HTML), make sure to use the correct escaping - but that's a *different* issue, so not quite sure why "html" is a tag.

Comment: @user3148173 All your questions are answered in the linked question.

Comment: As @user2864740 mentions, this question already have answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @jakeGould Yes all of these variables will be validated

Answer (score 0):

First of all **`mysql_*`** functions are deprecated. So switch to **`MySQLi`** or **`PDO`**.

Coming to your question..

Seems like you are worried about SQL Injection issues , If you use **`PreparedStatements`** you can very well avoid them (SQLi) as escaping is done automatically.

Comment: Seems like downvoter hates **PreparedStatements** and wants to stick on to `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for string and this [intval](http://php.net/intval) for integer

And for safer use this [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo)